# Rankine-Hugoniot jump condition linear system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

Ladies, gentlemen, I need your help with this one

Consider the linear system of equations

$u_t+Au_x=0$

with $u=(u_1,...,u_n)^T$ and $A\in n\times n$ matrix with constant entries.

Derive the Rankine-Hugoniot jump conditions for this system of linear hyperbolic equations

$A(u_l-u_r) =s(u_l-u_r) $

and show that $u_l-u_r$ is the eigenvector of $A$ and $s$ the associated eigenvalue.

I've tried to diag $A$ and then to decouple the system, but this doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried to diag $A$ and then to decouple the system, but this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure diagonalization works! Upon diagonalization, the proof is exactly the same as in the [scalar case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/865142/418542). The equality $A[\![u]\!]=s[\![u]\!]$ defines an eigenvalue problem, where $[\![u]\!]=u_l-u_r$ is the jump in $u$. Therefore, let us introduce the following eigendecomposition of the matrix $A$: $$
A = P \Lambda P^{-1} ,
$$
where the matrix $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1 , \dots , \lambda_n)$ is diagonal and presumably real. Then, introducing $v = P^{-1} u$, we have:
$$
v_t + \Lambda v_x = 0 ,
$$
which is a decoupled system of $n$ linear advection equations $v_{i,t} + \lambda_i v_{i,x} = 0$. The Rankine-Hugoniot condition implies $\lambda_i [\![v_i]\!] = s[\![v_i]\!]$ component-wise, i.e. $\Lambda [\![v]\!] = s[\![v]\!]$. Then, upon left-multiplication of the previous equation by $P$, we get the desired result $$A [\![u]\!] = s[\![u]\!] \, ,$$
where we have used $[\![v]\!] = P^{-1} [\![u]\!]$.

Comment: It was so simple and I failed :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: I dont know how to pm you, so i'll ask here and delete afterwards. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382259/prove-an-identity-for-the-continuous-integral-solution-of-the-conservation-law#comment8103019_382259 what does $u(\cdot, t) $ mean? Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058321/entropy-solution-of-burgers-equation-u-tu2-2-x-0/1060261#comment8110343_1060261 why is $r(6+4\sqrt{2})=4+2\sqrt{2}$?